# Error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up

Tags: react-native

I created the react-native project, then open the folder, at the terminal; After running "npm start" and then "react-native run-android" I was able to run it on the virtual device. However, when I do this from the vscode terminal, I get the following error;

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:621:13)
at runOnAllDevices (/home/myworldsoftware-u/İndirilenler/project2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (/home/myworldsoftware-u/İndirilenler/project2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:158:41)
at then.result (/home/myworldsoftware-u/İndirilenler/project2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:125:12)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
npx react-native doctor
```

This command checks your environment and displays a report of the status of `react-native` installation. Check the output carefully for other software you might need to install

Answer (score 1):

You should change distributionUrl in  ***android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*** to

**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip**

Answer (score 0):

*You need to make focus on 2 files to check them ..either they are present or not or the code inside them is correct...*
1.`local.properties file`

---

**A**.check that it is present or not..if yes go to step **a2** or if not then:

---

**a1.** then inside the **yourAppPath/Android/** you need to make a file with name `local.properties`

---

**a2.** And inside that put the path of android sdk

---

eg: `sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\UserNameDirectory\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk`

**B**.  inside  **yourAppPath/Android/setting.gradle**

---

**b1.** check if not present then add `include ':app'`

Answer (score 0):

- Open android folder on android studio
- Then wait of gradle build to complete
- Issue solved

Answer (score -1):

Put below line in your `android/gradle.properties` file:

```js
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: he's already there.
in the meantime I'm trying to run it via vscode-terminal.

Answer (score -1):

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have the same problem. At present, Android virtual machine can run normally, but running `react-native run-android` will cause such a problem

Comment: It is not cleat to me how this answers the question.