# i got an stuck in android development server i have facing an error after installation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Facing issue " Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment " in react native

I have facing an android development error who should I resolve it . I used npx react-native init project name and then I ran react-native run-android I have always seen an error of android development server
[image]

Comment: A simple search for that error message would have found https://stackoverflow.com/q/63068384/62576 It was also suggested to you as a possible duplicate when you wrote your question, but you chose to ignore it. Please spend some time researching the problem before posting a new question here.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58147568/62576 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58138912/62576

Comment: I have already use react-native doctor but issue is not solve

Comment: i just made an variable named ANDROID_HOME and set a sdk path on it and then i set the path of system variable and past node,npm ,tools,too-platform ,sdk,emulator,nodejs,npm

Answer (score 0):

It's a common pitfall for beginner. The error

> Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment ...

is misleading.

The real error is in the line

> What went wrong: The suppplied javaHome seems to be invalid

which suggest that you should check the value of your env variable `JAVA_HOME` and make sure it points to a valid Java installation directory.

And if you have checked it and cannot figure out the problem, you may find it useful to check this question  ([IntelliJ Gradle Plugin: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356796/intellij-gradle-plugin-the-supplied-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid)) out. For example, someone suggest that its possible root cause is the incompatible version (32/64 bit) of your JDK.